# Get Yarn application id before SparkSession is instantiated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When spark-submit submits an application to Yarn it's assigned an application id immediately. But from within the application the only way to get this id that I know of is `sparkSession.sparkContext.applicationId`.

Is there a way to get application id before SparkSession is instantiated? I am doing some prechecks, determining config options and I would like to have a way to log it already at this stage in case something goes wrong.

Comment: No is also an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the program there is not. As you imply yourself.